# Get Time Alone from MS Access Database using Javascript

Tags: ms-access

I have a column in my MS Access table which displays Time (hh:mm). 
However, when I retrieve this data using the below query, I seem to be getting the entire year along with the time.

I want to display just the time.

```
resultString = resultString +""Time Is : " + rs("Time");
rs.MoveNext();
```

Result:

```
Time Is : Sat Dec 30 14:00:00 UTC+0530 1899
```

I tried using `Hour([Time])` but it doesn't seem to fit in the above statement.

Comment: Why don't you use the hour function in your SQL so only the time is returned from the query?  Would save unnecessary additional data processing on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Try below vb code

```
 resultString = resultString + "Time Is : " + Format(CDate(rs("Time")), "hh:MM")
 rs.MoveNext
```

Comment: Object Expected Error. I was wondering if i could save the Hour"hh" to a variable and display the same;

something like this;
var x=rs("Time");--But this line is not the right way*any alternatives??*
var h=x.getHours();
resultString = resultString +""Time Is : " +x ;

thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Sorry but VB Just wont help  need this is Jscript. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: You have to convert your rs("time") into a date and then need to format it as hh:mm in javascript

Comment: Would be much easier if some one could at least advise how to reset the date/time column in MS Access Data Base to The current Year rather than pointing to December 1899.